# 2005 classic will start when cold but has trouble starting when warm

Tags: starting

when i start the car when cold it has no issue.

after it is at operating temp and shut it off and try to restart it it cranks with no fire, when you turn the key off and try it again it will fire.

took it to a chevy dealer and they said it did not happen for them.
when i picked it up and drove 3 miles to a store went in,  and was back out in a couple minutes, it would crank with no fire and started after 2nd try.

Has anyone had this experience before?

Comment: Are you talking about a Silverado?

Comment: @paulster2: Wikipedia suggests that the Chevy Classic was an alternate name for the Malibu midsize sedan (specifically for fleet sales). Maybe the OP can confirm that this is the vehicle in question here.

Answer (score 1):

If a vehicle struggles with hot starts but is fine with cold starts, it indicates that there is a lack of fuel pressure in the fuel lines.

This could be down to a few reasons:

- A minor leak/puncture in the fuel rail/lines that doesn't allow retention of pressure
- A stuck fuel injector that isn't closing completely
- Insufficient pressurization due to a weak fuel pump

---

The reason why fuel pressure plays an important role in hot starts is that fuel has a tendency to vaporize due to the heat from a hot engine. To combat this, the fuel line is kept under pressure to prevent/reduce vaporization from happening.

This also explains why the vehicle starts at the 2nd attempt - during the 1st start attempt the system has had the chance to pressurize the fuel line and purge the fuel vapors present.